# Passing one element of a struct into a function in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I know that several questions similar to mine have been asked before, and I have looked at many of them, but I can't seem to find one that accurately answers my question. Below is a minimal example for my code. It doesn't quite work, and I apologize for that. I'm really unfamiliar with stack overflow and coding in general. I'm trying to do the following:

1. Create a struct
2. Create a vectored instance of a struct
3. Pass one element of that vectored struct into a function.

However, when I do this, it will not compile. It gives the following errors:

```
make: *** [~~~~] Error 1

symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Where the "~~~~" is the name of my program. I feel like my problem is simple, like having to dereference a pointer or something, but no matter what I try, it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
typedef struct precinct {
    int geoID; 
    long int neighbors[21]; 
    double nhblength[21]; 
    double perim; 
    double area; 
    int county; 
    int startdist; 
    int dist; 
    int pop; 
    int moe; 
    int nhbindex[21]; 
} Prec;

//prototypes
int checkAdjacency(Prec P);

int main(void) 
{
    Prec *SCPrec = malloc(2233 * sizeof(Prec));

    /* In this space, I load in data for each precinct. For the sake of this MWE, I'll just show some of the data loaded for the first precinct */

    SCPrec[0].geoID = 40351;
    SCPrec[0].dist = 3;
    SCPrec[0].pop = 781;

    int value;
    value = checkAdjacency(SCPrec[0]);
    printf("%d\n",value);
    return 0;
}

int checkAdjancency(Prec P)
{
    if(P.dist==5)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do the messages around “symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64” also say “Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:” and “"_checkAdjacency", referenced from:”?

Comment: I don't see any sort of messages like that around my errors.

Comment: `checkAdjacency` and `int checkAdjancency(Prec P)` - look at them carefully and you will observe a typo.

Comment: That is strange. Usually the linker will list the symbols that are not defined. You should try to figure out why you are not seeing all of the output. Meanwhile, note that your `main` routine calls `checkAdjacency`, but your code defines `checkAdjancency`. Those are different.

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi Oh my goodness. I feel so stupid. Thank you so much. The code is working now.

Comment: @BSplitter No problem, happy to help. This should resolve your symbol issue.

Comment: _Side note:_ It's usually much more efficient to pass a _pointer_ to a `struct`. As you have it, the entire _contents_ of your `struct` has to be pushed onto the stack (i.e. `sizeof(Prec)` bytes) instead of just the pointer. Consider [before you write too muich code]: Changing `int checkAdjacency(Prec P)` to `int checkAdjancency(Prec *P)` using `P->dist` in the function body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You spelled `checkAdjacency` wrong.

For this, and other reasons, I prefer to avoid forward declarations unless they're necessary.

```
int checkAdjancency(Prec P)
{
    ...
}

int main(void) 
{
    ...
    value = checkAdjacency(SCPrec[0]);
    ...
}
```

This gives a clearer error message.

```
test.c:38:13: warning: implicit declaration of function 'checkAdjacency' is invalid in C99
      [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    value = checkAdjacency(SCPrec[0]);
            ^
1 warning generated.
```